# Youtube Embed video has huge black border

Tags: html, iframe, video, youtube, embed

I'm putting in an embed youtube video and it seams when first loaded it has this odd huge black padding around the youtube's first frame image. When played its fine but this is odd no?

I have looked a few other questions similar to this on here, and have tried their solutions of not having 'autohide=0' in my embed code but it still shows. It's very odd and I'm not sure how to resolve this.

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for the iframe.

```
<iframe width="653" height="367" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5ma2kUjRzBE?list=PLeT1J4FpHAWw7xZ8_brWOn4AmQv-e-dVp?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And this is what it looks like

[image: Youtube black box bug]

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get the embed code from youtube. You make right click in the video and it shows up the option to get the code ("Copy embed code").
Then you change it to include the `"http:"` part like this one:

`<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qUFhJ1V50gs?feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`
Try and tell me.

Comment: I did get the initial embed code from youtube, where else would of I got it from?

Comment: I did and it changes nothing, also it's on a live server so it redundant to have the http: anyway.

Comment: Probe with this with your video: `<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5ma2kUjRzBE?feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Now that I look more throught it. I think that's the new way in which youtube shows the videos.